# Chrome vs. IE11 image rendering difference

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, rendering

I am a Front-End developer.

Recently, I noticed about image rendering problem in IE11 on my desktop.

Here is the screenshots.

[IE11 .png rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofPET.png)

[Chrome 48.0 .png rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9vYd.png)

As you can see, there is difference in image quality between IE and Chrome.

My question is, if possible, how IE11 can show the image like the Chrome's.
(showed smoothly)